# Как оформить интонационно подчёркнутое слово?

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

> И, сосредоточившись на попытке понять замысел Микеланджело, **мы
>   должны попробовать – в прямом смысле этого слова: попробовать –
>   ощутить**. Мы должны повторить скульптуру своим телом, как минимум
>   умозрительно принять подобное положение и прислушаться.

Вокруг "попробовать" знаки мои.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы так написала:

И, сосредоточившись на попытке понять замысел Микеланджело, **мы должны "попробовать" его в прямом смысле этого слова: попробовать – значить чувственно ощутить.**

Пояснение

1) *Попробовать **замысел*** – условное выражение, отсюда кавычки. (Впрочем, это как вариант, так как условность объясняется).

2) Прямое значение ***пробовать*** – ощутит на вкус, поэтому вкус заменяем чувственным ощущением.

**ПРОБОВАТЬ,** 1. кого-что. Испытывать, проверять что-л. П. мотор. 2. **что. Есть или пить для пробы, чтобы определить вкус, готовность чего-л.** П. салат.  П. на вкус. 3. с инф. Пытаться, стараться что-л. сделать.